# Firefox downloads the .aspx file instead of showing generated pdf in new window

Tags: asp.net, firefox, pdf, webforms

I need to show a generated pdf file in a new browser window for asp.net web forms after clicking a button. Here is the sample code for opening new window inside the click event handler-

```
 string url = string.Format("report/RptMoneyReceipt.aspx?FN={0}", "StudentMoneyReceipt" + ".pdf");

 string script = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('" + url + "','pdf')</script>";             

 this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", script);
```

The code works fine in google chrome. But in firefox after creating a new browser window the browser always downloads the .aspx file instead of showing the pdf.

Comment: The firefox browser has PDF reader plugin enabled / installed? In other words, how a file is processed by a browser should be determined by the Content-Type field in the http Response Header; the file suffix should be ignored when there is a Content-Type field.The Content-Type should be application/pdf not text/html from mozilla forum

Comment: That's the problem actually. I can't find a way to define that!

Comment: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2035391 check this link.. might help

Comment: Well figured out that the problem is with the adobe acrobat pdf plugin. Just disabled that and everything works fine! -_-

Comment: you can upvote my first reponse :)